# VBA - ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex -4142 error by conditional formatting

Tags: vba, excel

I have a check which ensures that no cells in a row are filled with Red(colorindex 3) before carrying on with the function however the Interior.ColorIndex is weirdly returning '-4142'. Anyone experienced this before/notice an error in my code?

```
If UCase(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value) = "X" Then

  For i = 0 To 7
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
        MsgBox "Correct fields highlighted in red."
        Exit Sub

    End If
   Next
    ident = ActiveCell.Value
    verNo = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    title = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
    status = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
    location = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
    appDate = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value
    ccRef = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value
```

Where I initially add the highlighting:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Document Index").Range("B5:B500")
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(($B5=""""), 
$A5=""X"")"
    .FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(($B5<>""""), 
$A5=""X"")"
   .FormatConditions(2).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of reasons why the code does not work. And all of them are hidden in the part of the code that you do not show...

In general, just guessing, is that you do not have writing access to the sheet with the `ActiveCell`. Thus, you have to unlock it.

Another option can be, that you have selected a Chart, and not a worksheet.

A third option is that you are making some other tricks. In general, a plain code like this works:

```
Sub Test
    ActiveCell.Offset(0,0).interior.ColorIndex =3
End Sub
```

But I really think that the error is the first one I have pointed out, I get it when I lock the sheet with the `ActiveCell`:

[image]

Concerning color index in format condition, you should use the nice Functions, provided by Mr. Pearson:

```
Function ColorIndexOfCF(Rng As Range, _ 
    Optional OfText As Boolean = False) As Integer

Dim AC As Integer
AC = ActiveCondition(Rng)
If AC = 0 Then
    If OfText = True Then
       ColorIndexOfCF = Rng.Font.ColorIndex
    Else
       ColorIndexOfCF = Rng.Interior.ColorIndex
    End If
Else
    If OfText = True Then
       ColorIndexOfCF = Rng.FormatConditions(AC).Font.ColorIndex
    Else
       ColorIndexOfCF = Rng.FormatConditions(AC).Interior.ColorIndex
    End If
End If

End Function
```

http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/CFColors.htm

Comment: Yeah good point, but the sheet isn't locked. There must be some other reason why it can't access the cell which I'm not noticing. I also don't understand why it can't still read the cells properties when the sheets locked.

Comment: not sure what else I can show which is relevant, I've updated the main post with some more code. I definitely don't have any protection calls for this particular sheet.

Comment: I think I might see my mistake, the reference to the cell color is part of the format condition rather than actually being set to 3 in the cells properties? @vityata

Comment: thanks for helping me understand the problem(I will find a way to work around it so I marked it as an accepted answer) however I don't think your solution works; 16777215/-4142 seems to be returned regardless of cell color, so I also have blue fill which will return 16777215/-4142.

Comment: @KieranHughes - you are right, its kind of strange. Then you should simply use the good old CPearson - http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/CFColors.htm, it would help you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`-4142` is the `"no colour"` value (`xlColorIndexNone`)